# Use pivot_wider on table but keep count of rows

Tags: r, dplyr

So my problem is as follows, I have a small data frame like this:

```
test_df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,2), ttype=c("D", "C", "D", "D", "C"), val=c(1, 5, 10, 5, 100))
test_df
  id ttype val
1  1     A   1
2  1     B   5
3  2     A  10
4  2     A   5
5  2     B 100
```

Now I want to make it wider to end up like this:

```
     id        A        B     n
1     1        5        1     2
2     2      100       15     3
```

So I want to replace the `ttype` with a column for each value, grouped by id with the summed values of `val`. But my problem is that I still want to keep track of how many either A or B occurred in total for each id, which is `n` in this case.

Now I found a way to do this, but it is very ugly. But this way works:

```
test_df %>% 
  group_by(id, ttype) %>% 
  summarise(val = sum(val), n=n()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = ttype, values_from=c(val, n), values_fill=0) %>% 
  mutate(n=n_A+n_B) %>% 
  select(-n_A, -n_B)
```

results in:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
     id val_A val_B     n
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     1     5     1     2
2     2   100    15     3
```

So here the amount of A en B is included separately, after which I sum them and remove both other columns. But this means I have to hardcode column names and makes it not really doable when there are more than 2 values in ttype.

I feel like there must be a simple way to do this, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add count of `id` rows as new column and get data in wide format using `pivot_wider` by taking `sum` of `val` values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

test_df %>%
  add_count(id) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = ttype, values_from = val, values_fn = sum)

#     id     n     D     C
#  <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     2     1     5
#2     2     3    15   100
```